# Flutter check for month changes in dates

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I check for month-to-month changes between dates?
For example:

```
  DateTime a = DateTime(2022, 10, 01);
  DateTime b = DateTime(2022, 09, 22);
  if (...)
  print(isChange);
```

Output: true.

If:

```
  DateTime a = DateTime(2022, 09, 24);
  DateTime b = DateTime(2022, 09, 22);
  if (...)
  print(isChange);
```

Output: false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
bool isChange(DateTime a, DateTime b) {
   return a.month != b.month || a.year != b.year;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
DateTime a = DateTime(2022, 09, 24);
DateTime b = DateTime(2022, 09, 22);

print("ischange = ${isChange(a, b)}"); //ischange = false
```

Comment: This could be simplified to just `return a.month != b.month;`. You also should check the year so that October, 2022 isn't considered the same as October, 2021.

Comment: Oh, I forgot all about that property, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compare the `month` and `year` property

```
if (a.month == b.month && a.year == b.year) {
    // ...something else you want to do...
    print(false)
} else {
    // ...something else you want to do...
    print(true)
}
```

Comment: You also should check the year so that October, 2022 isn't considered the same as October, 2021.

Comment: Oh, I forgot all about that property, thank you!

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks! Totally forgot that lol